# Mechanism of Denigés' test?

Tags: organic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

According to Wikipedia, [Denigés' test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denig%C3%A9s%27_reagent) detects tertiary alcohols through their dehydration, marked with a colored precipitate. The reagent itself is some form of aqueous mercury(II) sulfate. My question is, what is the mechanism behind this reaction? I would assume there is some kind of electrophilic attack on the formed double bond as in oxymercuration, but I can't find any answers on what would occur from there or what the precipitate is.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's oxymercuration, with organomercury compound precipitating out.